# simulation for section 7.3 of I.Gertsbakh 's book "Reliablity Theory :with applications to preventive maintenance?

Tags: python

Here's is the link of the book:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-04236-6_7

please tell if there has been any simulation of this done before or else simulate the algorithm if possible.
I am not able to understand from where the data 0 and further data are being generated.

Comment: Please provide the **core** problems and clarify the **real** problem you are facing instead of a link.

Comment: Hi, i have given link of the book because it a concept given there whose simulation is bit tricky,to understand the simulation you should be able to understand the concept given in 7.3 section of the book